# Drupal add filter through php snippet

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I need to create a new filter for my view inside php snippet. Is it possible to do that using Drupal API? Can you also give me code example if possible?

Thank You,
Toliy

Comment: Ummm, you will need to post a much more detailed question then this in order to get the answer you require. We are here to help, we are not mind readers though ;)

Comment: I created a view which generate a list of movies for 2010. I need to alter the view to show the list of movies for 2009, but i don't want to change view in the CMS. I want to change the filter using PHP with the year passed as the argument.

Comment: Something like this:
localhost/?year=2009
<?php
// add filter to view here
?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment made much more sense ;)

What you are asking for is easily possible with Views out-of-the-box. Specifically, when you are in Views, lookk for the section called "Views arguments". To get you started there is a [massive tutorial on drupal.org about them](http://drupal.org/node/54455).

The path to your page will be something like:

```
movies/year/%
```

The character '%' signifies an argument